# SimpleXML: How to find number of children of top-level element?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

How do I find the number of children of the root element in an XML document using PHP and SimpleXML?

DLiKS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using PHP 5.3+ you can use [`SimpleXMLElement::count`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.count.php)

Otherwise, just do somthing like:

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$kids = $sxe->children();
echo count($kids);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( $string );
echo count( $xml );
```

or

```
echo $xml->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML represent XML nodes as arrays, so, you can simple use count() with simplexml object as argument count(simplexml_load_string( $string ))