# how to count the raw element fo the xml file?

Tags: php, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SimpleXML: How to find number of children of top-level element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055092/simplexml-how-to-find-number-of-children-of-top-level-element)
>   [php count xml elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386465/php-count-xml-elements)

I have got this code:

```
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<document>
 <title>Forty What?</title>
 <from>Joe</from>
 <to>Jane</to>
 <body>
  I know that's the answer -- but what's the question?
 </body>
</document>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$data_count = count($data->xml);
print_r($data_count);
```

I run this code on line [Demo](http://writecodeonline.com/php/)

when I perform `print_r($data_count);` the resualt is "0" instead 10(rows in the string);

what should I do to contain the numbers of the raw in the varible `$data_count` ?
many thx.

Comment: what do you mean by `instead 10(rows in the string);`

Comment: and lots more in the Related Section. Please use the search function before asking. We really mean it when we ask you to do your homework in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Comment: "*the resualt [sic] is "0" instead 10(rows in the string);*" — I'm struggling to see what you have 10 of, can you explain what a "row" is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<document>
 <title>Forty What?</title>
 <from>Joe</from>
 <to>Jane</to>
 <body>
  I know that's the answer -- but what's the question?
 </body>
</document>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string); 
$data_count = count($xml);//here you need to give the parser object
print_r($data_count);
echo count($xml->title); //No of title tags
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
print_r($xml->count()); // 4
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rE72A4)

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::count() in /homepages/26/d94605010/htdocs/lz/writecodeonline.com/php/index.php(201) : eval()'d code on line 16

Comment: what version of PHP are you using .. se a live demo here : http://codepad.viper-7.com/rE72A4 it workds

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this:

```
<?php

$string = "XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
  <document>
    <title>Forty What?</title>
    <from>Joe</from>
    <to>Jane</to>
    <body>
      I know that's the answer -- but what's the question?
    </body>
  </document>
XML";

$array = explode( "\r", $string );

print_r( sizeof( $array ) );

?>
```